# Nested enum and nested class have different behavior

Tags: c++

Consider these two examples:

```
struct X
{
    class E { static const int z = 16 };
    static const int b = X::z;   // X has no member z
};

struct Y 
{
    enum E { z = 16 };
    static const int b = Y::z;   // OK
};
```

Is there a section of the standard that explains this behavior?

Comment: Why is it not `X::E::z` ?

Comment: C++11 introduces `enum class` which gets rid of this name injection, bringing these uses closer together. It may be generally recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are such sections in the C++ Standard.

The first one is

**9.9 Nested type names**

> 1 Type names obey exactly the same scope rules as other names. In
>   particular, type names defined within a class definition **cannot be
>   used outside their class without qualification**.

It would be more precisely to cite the following quote

> 2 The name of a class member shall only be used as follows: — in the
>   scope of its class (as described above) or a class derived (Clause 10)
>   from its class, — after the . operator applied to an expression of the
>   type of its class (5.2.5) or a class derived from its class, — after
>   the -> operator applied to a pointer to an object of its class (5.2.5)
>   or a class derived from its class, — after the :: scope resolution
>   operator (5.1) applied to the name of its class or a class derived
>   from its class.

and the second one is

**11.7 Nested classes**

> 1 A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as
>   any other member. The members of an enclosing class have no special
>   access to members of a nested class; **the usual access rules (Clause 11)
>   shall be obeyed**.

In this definition if do not take into account a typo (the absence of a semicolon after the definition of z)

```
struct X
{
    class E { static const int z = 16 };
    static const int b = X::z;   // X has no member z
};
```

You are trying to access z 1) without qualification and 2) that has private access control.

The correct definition could look as

```
struct X
{
    class E { public: static const int z = 16; };
    static const int b = E::z;
};
```

As for the enumeration then enumerators of an unscopped enumeration are members of the class where the enumeration is defined.

**9.2 Class members**

> 1 The member-specification in a class definition declares the full set
>   of members of the class; no member can be added elsewhere. Members of
>   a class are data members, member functions (9.3), nested types, and
>   **enumerators**.

Answer (score 3):

> `[C++11: 7.2/10]:` Each *enum-name* and each *unscoped* enumerator is declared in the scope that immediately contains the *enum-specifier*. *[..]*

No such rule exists for classes.

Comment: How this implies that enum members can be accessed from the outer declarative region?

Comment: @St.Antario: The members are called _enumerators_. That's how.

Comment: /cc @zavhoz 

Answer (score 1):

You asked for citations from the Standard, and you've got the right ones, but it seems they don't help:

> How this implies that enum members can be accessed from the outer declarative region? –  St.Antario
>
> +1 to St.Antario. I don't understand it to. –  zavhoz

So I'll try the investigative approach. If we fix the irrelevant bugs in your
example `struct X`:

- Missing `;` after 16.
- `E::z` is priviate.

We have:

```
struct X
{
    struct E { static const int z = 16; };
    static const int b = X::z;
};
```

Compiling your code thus fixed, clang 3.4 complains:

```
error: no member named 'z' in 'X'; did you mean 'E::z'?
static const int b = X::z;
                     ^~~~
                     E::z
```

(gcc 4.9.0 and VC++ 2013 gives errors at the same line, but with less helpful
diagnostics)

No such complaint about `Y::z`, however. The lesson seems to be:

- A class definition does *not* declare the class members in the enclosing
  scope.
- A plain old enum definition *does* declare the enumerators in the
  enclosing scope.

I say *plain old enum* here, because as of C++11 we have also got a new fancier
kind of enum, but `Y::E` is a plain old one.

If that's the lesson, it does not appear to have anything in particular
to do with *nesting*.

Vlad from Moscow has cited you a paragraph of the Standard from **11.7 Nested classes**
from which he presumably wants you to gather that nesting is irrelevant to your
puzzle. But the fact that the compiler barfs at the qualified name `X::z`
and does not barf at the qualified name `Y::z` makes it look as if the
nesting of *struct* `E` in struct `X` has some significance that the nesting of
*enum* `E` in struct `Y` does not.

Recall that for any name `N` that is declared in a scope `S`, the
qualification `S::N` is *redundant* within the scope of `S`, just as the
qualification `::N` is redundant at global scope for a global name `N`.

*If* there is something declared `z` in the scope of `X`[`Y`], then within the scope of
`X`[`Y`] you can refer to it as just `z`. So let's delete the superfluous
qualifications from the example code:

```
struct X
{
    struct E { static const int z = 16; };
    static const int b = z;
};

struct Y 
{
    enum E { z = 16 };
    static const int b = z;
};
```

and see what clang makes of it now:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'z'; did you mean 'E::z'?
static const int b = z;
                     ^
                     E::z
```

It has just the same problem in `X`; still has no problem in `Y`. But since
we've got rid of the superfluous qualification, `X` *isn't mentioned at all.*

And `Y` has *never* been mentioned. So maybe now it no longer looks as if
nesting has something to do with the puzzle.

So next let's go ahead and get rid of `X` and `Y`. Here's the program:

```
struct E { static const int z = 16; };
static const int b = z;
enum E1 { z = 16 };
static const int b = z;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And clang says:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'z'; did you mean 'E::z'?
static const int b = z;
                     ^
                     E::z
```

No change at all.

So nesting has, indeed, nothing to do with the puzzle. The fact of the matter *is*
that struct|class members are declared in the struct|class scope, *not*
in the enclosing scope, and the enumerators of a plain old enum are declared in the
*enclosing scope*. Lightness Races in Orbit has given you the Standard reference
for the latter fact.

Does this still surprise you? It can hardly suprise you that:

```
struct E { static const int z = 16; };
static const int b = z;
```

does not declare `z` in the same scope as `b`. So possibly it suprises you that:

```
enum E1 { z = 16 };
static const int b = z;
```

*does* declare `z` in the same scope as `b`? Well, that is how plain old enums
have always been, since C++ inherited them and C. That is largely what makes
them *plain old* enums.

This scope-hoisting trait of plain old enums is the reason why, in C++11
jargon, plain old enums are called *unscoped enums*. And this trait, as
well as the readiness of unscoped enumerators to decay to `int`, has
made unscoped enums long a source of discomfort in C++.

Hence in C++11 we now have a more strictly behaved alternative, called a *scoped enum* or
*enum class* which goes something like this:

```
enum struct SE : short {
    z = 16
};
//const int b = z; <- Undeclared identifier
//const short b = SE::z; <- No implicit conversion
SE b = SE::z; //OK
const int c = static_cast<int>(SE::z); //OK
```

It looks as if scoped enums would not surprise you as to the scoping
of their enumerators but *would* suprise you by resisting implicit
integral conversions.

[Further reading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).